# New Pressure Tank Woes

Tags: water, water-pressure, pump, well

I have a new pressure tank (WX-202) and don't think it's set up properly. Set at 40/60, I should have a drawdown of 5.4 gallons according to spec. I'm getting about 3.5 gallons before the pump kicks back in. Also, the well pump fills the tank to 60psi in just under 20 seconds. I realize my pump is probably too much for the tank, and will be installing a CSV anyway. But i still feel there is something else wrong in this system.

Comment: Calculated values get you in the ball park I doubt there is anything wrong other than a undersized pressure tank IMO.

Comment: Turn off the well pump, drain down the tank to zero psi, pre-charge the pressure tank to 38 psig,turn the water back on and walk away. Don't fret over a slightly different draw down than the specs.

Comment: I will try that. Doing some calculations, it appears the precharge was set way too low.

Comment: I checked the pre-charge and it is set correctly (38psi). I do feel two gallons less than spec is more than a "slightly"  different value.